# How do I enable any domain to log into my Azure Active Directory app

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory

My current application supports Microsoft and Google oAuth verification sign in.  The idea is to give users the option of signing in with their personal accounts for ease of access.  This is working fine with google, but AAD will only allow users with emails that end in the App ID URI domain to sign in

eg: App Id URI = someOrg.com/guid and their sign in = someUser@someOrg.com.
Attempting to sign in with a Microsoft account like an outlook or hotmail account redirects to a page saying 
"We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later."

Is there a way to allow AAD to accept any Microsoft account in the login, or can it only accept users in a single domain?

Comment: Note that it is just a coincidence in your case that "someOrg.com" is part of your app ID URI. You could change that to a different value, if you wanted to. As Daniel describes in his answer, what's specifically coming in play is the fact that you are likely using a tenant-specific endpoint, which is what is restricting it to users from the Azure AD tenant.

Answer (score 2):

#### Basics

Yes! Checkout https://aka.ms/aadv2. The v2 endpoint allows both personal Microsoft and Azure AD accounts to be signed in from a single app reg. You'll need to hit this special endpoint (can be done using the MSAL libraries) and setting your app audience in the Azure portal.

#### Details...

By default and using the following URLs (note the `common` piece):

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/token`

If set to common, your app can sign in any domain and personal Microsoft accounts.

#### Other options

For the sake of covering everything, here's the other options:

***common***->***organizations***: Only allow Azure AD accounts

***common***->***consumers***: Only allow personal Microsoft accounts

***common***->***[tenant_id]***: Only allow accounts from the specified tenant

#### MSA as a guest

The edge case you may need to address is a personal Microsoft account added as a guest to an Azure AD tenant. When the user hits `common`, they'll be signed in as a personal Microsoft account; however, they may intend to sign into their domain. You can build around this by introducing a "enter your email" screen, then passing this as a hint to Microsoft via the `common` endpoint.